# Is this correct modelling approach? Class diagram example

Tags: class, uml, class-diagram, diagramming

I'm trying to model chess game. My UML-newbie thinking goes like this:
GameEngine has just one chessboard and two players (who inherits from Player) and when GameEngine is destroyed, so are these (composition). Chessboard can contain up to 32 chessmen and each player can control/have references to 16 chessmen (aggregation). The players need to call or access some methods of the board (directed association).
Is that correct or at least close?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made abstraction `Player` over `Human` and `CPU`. I think all your arrows must use the common one `Player`. For example:

```
class Chessboard {
  Player p1;
  Player p2;
}
```

It is more convenient way, and you can change in runtime your players and different game modes: Human vs Human, Human vs CPU, even CPU vs CPU

The same changes applied to GameEngine.

By the way, I don't think it is a good idea to player aggregate controlled chessmen. All control over `Chessman` nut be responsibility of `Chessboard`, and player just send him a message when he want to make a move in his turn.

That change allows you to have several chessboards per player for multi-table game.

Comment: Well I was thinking about that butI'm not sure because the player is abstract class and therefore cannot be instantionated - that is why I think it cannot be used like that. The chessman aggregation is because players start with chessmen and place them to the board, so the board actually only contains references to object created in player classes. (slightly different from regular chess).

Comment: @user970696 You can't instantiate abstract but can use `Player p1 = new Human()`. Yout chessboard will work with `Player`'s API. You should separate Chessman from Player, actually Player just send command to Chessboard, which is responsible to create Chessman

Comment: I did not make it clear. In this kind of chess, players have chessmen outside the board and place them. The game starts with 0 chessmen on the board. That is why I think player should be responsible for them. I would not create Players inside the Chessboard but inside the GameEngine.